# Trouble Calculating Integral of Absolute Value of Polynomials using Maxima and abs_integrate

Tags: polynomials, maxima-minima, absolute-value, maxima-software

I am currently working on a Maxima script that is supposed to calculate the definite integral from `-1` to `1` of the absolute value of any given polynomial `p`. In my case, I've chosen `p` to be `x^3-1/4`, but it could be any other polynomial.

```
load("abs_integrate");
normaU(p):=integrate(abs(p),x,-1,1);
normaU(x^3-(1/4));
```

When I run the code, Maxima returns the integral expression `integrate(abs(x^3-1/4),x,-1,1)`, but does not evaluate it.

**What's troubling is that this issue only arises when the polynomial is of degree 3 or higher. For lower degree polynomials, the integration seems to work fine.**

I couldn't find much information about the `abs_integrate` package and how it works, which is why I'm turning to this community for help.

Can anyone explain why this might be happening and how I could go about solving this issue? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It is not clear that it's supposed to work, and more likely not. From the [documentation](https://maxima.sourceforge.io/docs/manual/de/maxima_181.html): "*The package `abs_integrate` extends Maxima’s integration code to some integrands that involve the absolute value, max, min, signum, or unit step functions. For integrands of the form $p(x) \,|q(x)|$, where p is a polynomial* ***and q is a polynomial that factor is able to factor into a product of linear or constant terms***, *the abs_integrate package determines an antiderivative that is continuous on the entire real line*".